# Overwriting parent function in multiple children

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a couple of child classes that I want to use but they both inherit a method from their parent that doesn't quite behave the way I need it to.

```
class ParentClass():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def annoying_funct(self):
        print("I don't do quite what's needed and print {0}".format(self.value + 1))
    def other_parent(self):
        print("I do other useful things my children inherit")

class Child1(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, value, new_value1):
        super(Child1, self).__init__(value)
        self.new_value1 = new_value1
    def other_child1(self):
        print("I do useful child things")

class Child2(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, value, new_value2):
        super(Child2, self).__init__(value)
        self.new_value2 = new_value2
    def other_child2(self):
        print("I do other useful child things")
```

I want to overwrite `annoying_funct()` as something like this:

```
def annoying_funct():
    print("I behave the way I am needed to and print {0}".format(self.value))
```

`ParentClass`, `Child1` and `Child2` are from a very complex library (`scikit-learn`), so I want to keep all of my wrappers as thin as possible.  What would be the cleanest/most pythonic way of getting the functionality of my two child classes while altering the parent class as needed?

My thoughts so far:

Create a new class that inherits from the parent which overwrites the function I don't like and then make wrapper classes for the children that inherit from the new class and the child classes.

```
class NewParentClass(ParentClass):
    def annoying_funct(self):
        print("I behave the way I am needed to and print {0}".format(self.value))

class NewChild1(NewParentClass, Child1):
    pass

class NewChild2(NewParentClass, Child2):
    pass
```

My areas of confusion:

1. Is this the correct approach?  It seems a little weird and klugy.  Is there a cleaner way of doing this?
2. Is the syntax used for the two child classes correct?  It runs for me, but it seems a little weird having them do nothing but inherit and pass.
3. Is having my new parent inherit from the previous parent the correct way of doing this?  The code runs for the children without the inheritance between `parentClass` and `newParentClass` (eg. `def newParentClass():`), but if someone tried to make an instance of `newParentClass()` the function wouldn't work because it uses attributes not present in that class (`value`).  Is that ok if I assume the class will never be used?

Comment: Why not overwrite the `annoying_funct` in child1 and child2?

Comment: 1) `child1` and `child2` are both `scikit-learn` functions so `newChild1` and `newChild2` will be necessary either way 2) it seems redundant to alter `annoying_funct` twice to do the same thing, particularly since `annoying_funct` is ~200 lines of reasonably complex code that I don't want to fix bugs in two different places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using the concept of a [mixin](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/mixins-and-python) to add my new functionality to the child classes.  The resulting code was as follows:

```
class AnnoyMixin:
    def well_behaving_func(self):
        print("I behave the way I am needed to and print {0}".format(self.value))

class NewChild1(AnnoyMixin, Child1):
    def annoying_funct(self):
        return well_behaving_func(self)

class NewChild2(AnnoyMixin, Child2):
    def annoying_funct(self):
        return well_behaving_func(self)
```

Functionally, this mostly behaves the same as the code I had proposed in my question, but the modifications help with readability.  First, by naming the new parent as a "Mixin" it makes it clear that this class is not designed to stand on its own, but rather is intended to add functionality to another class.  Because of this, `AnnoyMixin` doesn't need to inherit from `ParentClass`, simplifying inheritance for the `NewChild` classes.

Second, rather than overwriting `annoying_funct` in `AnnoyMixin`, we create the new function `well_behaving_func`.  It is then the `NewChild` classes job to overwrite `annoying_funct` by calling `well_behaving_func`.  Functionally, this works more or less the same as if the `AnnoyMixin` had over written `annoying_funct`, but this way, it is clearer to those reading the code that `annoying_funct` is being overwritten in the `NewChild` classes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do what you ask.

1. Create a new class inheriting from the parent class, then use it as new parent class.

The only drawback for this solution is that the when you provide the new parent or child class to functions requiring the original Parent class might not work since they might use `annoying_funct` and rely on an annoying behavior.

```
class NewParentClass:
    def annoying_funct(self):
       print("I behave the way I am needed to and print {0}".format(self.value))

class NewChild1(NewParentClass):
    pass

class NewChild2(NewParentClass):
    pass
```

2. Manipulate the existing Parent class

This is the solution I would like to use since it destroys the `annoying_funct` completely by replacing it with a well behaving one, buy again, other methods and functions requiring the former `annoying_funct` might fail. The good side is, you don't need to create another parent class and children, so your code will be much more elegant.

```
class ParentClass():
    ...
    def annoying_funct(self):
        print("I don't do quite what's needed and print {0}".format(self.value + 1))
   ...


def well_behaving_func(s):
    print("Good")

# Dynamically change the class method    
ParentClass.annoying_func = well_behaving_func

class Child1(Parent):
    pass

class Child2(Parent):
    pass

c = Child1()
c.annoying_funct() # prints 'Good'
```

3. Add a well behaving new method to parent class before inheriting from it.

If you want to maintain the current behavior and don't want your existing code or packages dependent on the parent class break, you certainly should not overwrite the `annoying_funct` in the parent class. So you should define a well behaving function and use it in child classes.

```
class ParentClass():
    ...
    def annoying_funct(self):
        print("I don't do quite what's needed and print {0}".format(self.value + 1))
   ...   

def well_behaving_func(s):
    print("Good")

# Dynamically change the class method    
ParentClass.well_behaving_func = well_behaving_func

class Child1(Parent):
    pass

class Child2(Parent):
    pass

c = Child1()
# use 'well_behaving_func', not the annoying one
c.well_behaving_func() # prints 'Good'
```

Comment: Thanks, they all look interesting.  Could you add any advantages or potential downsides as you see them?  It is a little hard to tell why I would choose to do one over the others.  Also I noticed that you have `Child1` and `Child2` inherit from parent and pass.  How do they get the `other_child1()` and `other_child2()` functions from the imported library?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but this still doesn't deal with the functions from `Child1` and `Child2`.  The child classes in the library have a bunch attributes and methods I need, this code just overwrites those classes and makes the children copies of the parent.  For method 2 I tried defining `class NewChild1(ParentClass, Child1)` but it couldn't create a MRO, and `class NewChild1(Child1, ParentClass)` left `annoying_funct()` as it is in the library for the `newChildClass`.  In short, it doesn't seem to work.